# String delete in VIM

Tags: regex, linux, vim

I have a file that has the general form as

```
number,number,string
```

and i want to delete both the numbers from each line and extract only the string. What would the regexp be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
:s/^[0-9]*,[0-9]*,//
```

For the whole file, that's:

```
:%s/^[0-9]*,[0-9]*,//
```

Comment: @Prasanth Madhavan Accept answer if it helps you to express your thanks :)

Comment: I'd just like to add that you can use '\d' instead of '[0-9]' if you prefer.  There are quite a few shortcuts like this that can make regular expressions easier to read, especially in vim's crazy regex world.  You can get a whole list of those which vim supports just under `:help /\i`.

Comment: \d is any numeric character but \D is any character BUT numeric characters.  It's actually quite useful and easy to overlook.

Comment: The first suggestion is missing ':' before the substitute command (for noobs). Yeah, @Prasanth, you should probably give viraptor credit for kindly answering your question :)

Comment: Just went ahead and made the edit myself (hope y'all don't mind)

Comment: Are negative numbers and ones with decimal places not numbers?

Comment: Also I would replace `*` with `\+` (there must be at least one digit). This would give: `:%s/^\(\d\+,\)\{2}//`

Comment: @all : thanks for helping me out.. was in a blackout for 2 days.. thats y the late credit.
@viraptor : thanks once again mate.. :)

Answer (score 2):

A good regular expression may be:

```
/^\(\s*[+-]*[[:digit:]]*\.*[[:digit:]]\+,\s*\)\{2}/
```

This will match numbers, including an optional sign and an optional decimal point (assuming you use `.` in your locale) followed by a comma and optional whitespace twice at the beginning of the line.

Usage:

```
:%s/^\(\s*[+-]*[[:digit:]]*\.*[[:digit:]]\+,\s*\)\{2}//
```

Add hex digits (`[[:xdigit:]]`) to taste.